# Merging CSV Files & Add Column to Each

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have multiple CSV files I'm trying to merge, but need to add a month or other identifier to each.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

all_data = pd.DataFrame()

files = [file for file in os.listdir('/Users/my_username/Desktop/campaign_mb_2020')]

for file in files:
    file['month'] = [i for i in range(len(files))]
```

I'd ideally like each file to contain a month column, but I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: in your code, the files variable has the name of your files, and not the file's content,i was trying to give you the solution for your problem, but i need more details from your part like the content of this CSV files, and also where you want to add the month

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd


p = Path('/Users/my_username/Desktop/campaign_mb_2020')

dfs = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file).assign(month=num) 
                             for num,file
                             in enumerate(p.glob('*.csv'))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning column to a string. you first need to read csv files and then assign a month value and then concat them:

```
df = pd.concat(
    [pd.read_csv(file).assign(file = file) for file in files]
).assign(
    month = lambda x: x['file'].str.slice(start=2,stop=10)
)
```

Comment: This makes sense. But when I run I am now getting: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: try this code and then you can use the file column to extract month of the file and assign the month value. 2 and 10 are examples and you have to match it with your own file names